# How to make SendMessage unblocking?

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

I have this script to turn the monitors off.

```
import win32api, win32con
print "start"
win32api.SendMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND, win32con.SC_MONITORPOWER, 2)
print "end"
```

`"end"` isn't printed and the script never ends.

It's annoying when the terminal windows stays open.

How do I make `SendMessage` non-blocking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't make `win32api.SendMessage()` non-blocking because the underlying Windows function is blocking. Instead you can use `win32api.PostMessage()`, it has the same signature:

```
import win32api, win32con

print "start"
win32api.PostMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND, win32con.SC_MONITORPOWER, 2)
print "end"
```

Comment: [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx) and [PostMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944.aspx) do not have the same signature. While `SendMessage` returns the value, that is the result of processing the message, `PostMessage` returns a boolean success code.

Comment: @IInspectable: you're probably right, I can't test it. I meant that same function arguments are passed. Neither are documented as returning anything in the PyWin32 documentation, but I think that `SendMessage` will return an integer, while `PostMessage` seems to return and error or `None`, not a boolean.

Comment: If the PyWin32-wrapper for `SendMessage` isn't documented to return anything, then either `SendMessage` is useless (if it doesn't return anything), or the documentation (for omitting a vital piece of information).